# How can I filter a collection in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

I have a list of elements (each element is a string), I need to keep only some of elements based on a async method taking in parameter the element and returning true (keep the element), false otherwise.

I tried the first solution, with the filter method, but as my criteria method is async it was not working, all the promises were considered true.

```
const elements = ["a","b"...]
const filteredElements = elements.filter(elem => hasAccess(elem))
async hasAccess(elem): Promise<boolean>
{
// return true of false depending of the input element
}
```

filteredElements contains all the elements here even the unauthorized

I'm trying a second solution, (I do not want to process each element one after one) :

```
const elements = ["a","b"...]
const filteredElementsPromises = elements.map(elem => hasAccess(elem))
async hasAccess(elem): Promise<boolean>
{
// return true of false depending of the input element
}
const results = await Promise.all(filteredElementsPromises)
```

in results, I get what I want, a list of booleans telling me if an element is accessible or not, but those are just boolean, I don't know to which element its rattached, for example, if I have results = [true,false], how can I know that the true is for element a or for element b, as the promises are not resolved in the initial order I guess